# Next Scheduled Run empty when using System.scheduleBatch in managed package

Tags: schedulebatch

I'm trying to debug this recent issue. Code works fine in scratch orgs, but when ran in managed package scheduleBatch seems to never execute. I wonder if there's some throttling going on as we use this mechanism to chain batch jobs (although this happens on very first use of method, not far into chain).

Is there some ways to debug this (can't see our own logs, ugh.)

Edit: adding some screenshots. Note after Next Scheduled Run the CronTrigger.State changes to deleted. No debug log gets generated ‍♂️

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do [Troubleshooting in Subscriber Organizations](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.apex_debugging_sub_org.htm&type=5). When you [Log In to Subscriber Orgs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_logging_in_to_sub_org.htm) from a License Management App-enabled org, you can either use the [ISV Customer Debugger](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/isv-debugger/) or you can get ISV-only logs from the [Developer Console](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.code_dev_console.htm&type=5). You'll need to [Request Login Access from a Customer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/lma_requesting_login_access.htm) before you can use these features, however.

In general, there is no additional throttling that happens when scheduling jobs, but do be aware that the [Execution Governors and Limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_gov_limits.htm) restrict an org to 100 scheduled jobs in total (including Scheduled Batchable jobs). Make sure you're not exceeding these limits. You should be able to use a try-catch block to detect when this situation occurs:

```
try {
  System.scheduleBatch('jobName',new BatchableClass(), minutesFromNow);
} catch(AsyncException e) {
  // Can't schedule job for some reason
} catch(StringException e) {
  // Invalid job name, etc
}
```

Comment: So this is a fresh dev org, fresh app install. Job succeeds in scheduling, but has no timeframe to execute it... :D

Comment: Dunno why Salesforce limits this `Package and subscriber org namespace collision, Details: The installing package namespace and org namespace cannot be the same.` - would solve so much debugging problems! Just let us install package under same ns so we can view logs!

Comment: @dzh Because the components would conflict. I agree it's not ideal, but Scratch Orgs are supposed to be how you do this kind of testing. You should still be able to get logs with Login Access, though.

Comment: Worked with my superior to get some logs. Aura logs are fully fledged, however batch apex are still useless as most of it is obfuscated...

Answer (score 1):

In order to get logs from a subscriber org containing info from your package's Apex you need to make sure you:

1. Gain login access for your "support" (request login access and have it granted).
2. Login via your PBO's Subscribers tab.
3. Create a new User Trace Flags through Setup > Environments > Log > Debug Logs (this must be done using the subscriber login grant), making sure to provide adequate time coverage for your needs and using a "log type" that has debug, fine or better Apex tracing.
4. Execute the required processing on the subscriber org with whichever user you set up the trace flags for.
5. Open the Debug Log using the same login as step 2.

As long as you follow these steps appropriately you will be able to get unobfuscated and detailed logs from your package on the subscriber org.

It should be noted that you might be bumping into [this issue](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V0000015KAbQAM) and I would encourage you and your team mates to upvote it to help get this problem resolved.

Comment: Cherry on top is you can't see debug logs from batch apex, unless you raise a case with Salesforce support.

Comment: @dzh that isn't my experience. You simply need to make sure that the batch apex runs under the same user as you have set up the trace flags for.

Comment: @dzh please do also note the "issue" link I provided.

Comment: The issue I observe only between my package API versions. Dunno about your experience, but we've tried to get some logs out todo and we could only see aura side of things. Whenever batch runs it's `ENTERING_MANAGED_PKG`.

Comment: That implies one of a) you didn't create the user trace flags via the subscriber login user or b) you're not using the correct subscriber login (if you have different packages on different LMOs) or c) you've not set the Debug Levels correctly for Apex. Or perhaps you are trying to debug a 2GP and this behaves differently compared with a 1GP (which is my only experience from the debugging perspective so far).

Comment: I agree I might have messed up trace flag creation, but that does not explain why I only one side of things - aura is fine (which normally isn't) while batch is not.

Comment: Does the batch run directly in the invoking user's context or is it run via an apex platform event subscriber trigger? If the latter you would need a trace flag against the Automated Process user. TBH, I'm grasping at straws...